# Loading nested JSON files in EC2 from S3 and using Python for iterations?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-pig

I am working on ~400 MB nested JSON files that are resting on the Amazon S3 server, performing some analysis using a Pig script that requires nearly 100 iterations (using Python for this).

As things stand, the data is loaded into EC2 for every iteration and each iteration is taking an hour for execution.

I am using one `16 core` and ten `4 core` instances.

1. Is there a way such that I do not load the data in each iteration?
2. What might be the reasons for this slow processing?
3. What should be my cluster configuration for optimizing processing time?

Comment: 400MB shouldn't take more than a minute or two to transfer, unless its thousands of small files. In that case you are better off zipping everything up and unzipping before the work begins.

Comment: There are about a 1000 zipped files that I am unzipping before processing in pig

Comment: I tried opening it using Textloader and it took just around 20 seconds. Could this be because of the combination of a nested json structure and large number of files?

Comment: I don't think loading is the issue. The data size is such that its unlikely to take more than a couple of minutes. How well does your processing handle threading?

Comment: I am writing pig embedded python codes. I use python for just looping purpose.. parallel execution is done at pig end. I use run() method instead of runSingle() in pig.